# Angular selector component lifecycles - ngoninit/ngondestroy/etc. are triggered if nested one under another. Can this behavior be avoided?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an app where I have a structure of a page something like this:

Object rendered from Firestore (posted item like in instagram)

- Comments are loaded (take id of object above to render comments sub collection)

  - Replies are loaded (take id of object and comment above to render replies sub collection)

Here is what it is from code point of view - simplified version:

```
<div class="container">
  {{ object.data.text }}
  {{ object.data.likes.length }}
  <comment objectid="{{object.id}}">
</div>
```

**Comment** selector

I have a template that is like this - simplified version:

```
<div *ngFor="let comment of comments | async" class="container">
  {{ comment.data.text }}
  {{ comment.data.likes.length }}
  <reply commentid="{{comment.id}}">
</div>
```

**Replies** selector

I have a template that is like this - simplified version:

```
<div *ngFor="let reply of replies | async" class="container">
  {{ comment.data.text }}
</div>
```

**Issue:** when comment.data.likes.length changes for the object, reply selector goes through full ngoninit and ngondestroy lifecycle. However,if object.data.likes.length changes, no lifecycle trigger is happening for comment nor for reply selector. The end user will see replies being refreshed on front end each time someone likes a comment, which is not a pleasant experience.

Has anyone faced this issue before or knows how to resolve it?

Comment: You can avoid re-creating every element from your `*ngFor`s by implementing a `trackBy` function. See https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#ngForTrackBy - Is this what you mean to ask about?

Comment: Also instead of `commentid="{{comment.id}}"` use the cleaner sytax of `[commentid]="comment.id"`

Comment: @Akxe - yep, that's a minor one, but good point hehe.

Comment: @Zircon - yes, that resolved the issue, finally :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that everytime the array inside the `*ngFor` changes it reference, angular is re-rendering all the items again because he cannot know which item has changed, so he removes everything and puts back again.

What you need to do is implement the `trackBy` function, which will tell Angular how to compare the objects inside the for, and watch if they have changed or not. Knowing that he will be able to just replace the items that have changed, instead of replacing everything again.

So, instead of

`*ngFor="let comment of comments | async"`,

you need:

`*ngFor="let comment of comments | async; trackBy: myTrackByFn"`

Where `myTrackByFn` is a function that you will implement in the `.ts` file:

```
myTrackByFn(index, item) {
    return item.id; // add the unique key for the item being iterated
}
```

Remember to implement this function for all of the three `*ngFor` you have.